# Install Ubuntu (MATE) along side pre-installed Windows which was installed with RAID configuration

Tags: boot, dual-boot, raid, mate, alienware

I am trying to install Ubuntu Mate 16.02 LTS on a Dell new Alienware 13 machine which has Windows 10 pre-installed. The problem is that it does not seem that I can install without changing RAID to AHCI in BIOS (otherwise Ubuntu installation won't detect the hard drive) and if I change to AHCI the pre-installed windows does not boot. I have looked the problem up and it seems that the only solution to have these two OSs together is re-installing windows using AHCI configuration. My question is can I still install Ubuntu MATE without re-installing Windows?

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10 (and probably other Win versions), the solution is to boot Windows in safe mode after changing RAID to AHCI in BIOS. The details can be found [here](http://triplescomputers.com/blog/uncategorized/solution-switch-windows-10-from-raidide-to-ahci-operation/).